# Cannot connect my ms access with java

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

I tried multiple ways to connect my database from ms access 2010 with java but it doesn't work.

1. I set the ODBC driver path from 64 bits to 32 bits by changing the path in property to `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.
2. I downloaded the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable for AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe in this website. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255

I researched most of the website and they told us to download the database engine 2010.
However, I still receiving this error:

> [Microsoft] [ODBC driver manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application.

Does anybody can post a step by step guide to solve my problem? Any help will be appreciated.

**Current Source Code**

```
private Connection con; 
public void setUp(String dsn) {
    try { 
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Load driver error"); 
    } try { 
        String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn; 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", ""); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) { 
    ResultSet rs = null; 
    try { 
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return rs; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your java code?

Comment: private Connection con;

 public void setUp(String dsn) {
  try {
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Load driver error");
  }
  try {
  
   String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) {
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return rs;
 }

Comment: Usually you'd edit your original question to show the source code.  I'll put it in there, but you might want to fix formatting.

Comment: Your JDBC connection bit looks solid, so the problem probably has to do with the setup of the ODBC.  Unfortunately I'm no expert in ODBC and MS-Access...

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a 64 bit JVM and 64 bit MS-Access is a little different than 64 bit.  Here's someone who's gone through the same pain as you and [written an article](http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/) on how to solve the problem.

Basically if your using the 64 bit library, you need to change up your connection string a bit.  Use this:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
```

where filename is a string of the full path to your access file, instead of:

```
String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn; 
con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
```

Comment: But here is my code.

private Connection con;

 public void setUp(String dsn) {
  try {
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Load driver error");
  }
  try {
  
   String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) {
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return rs;
 }

Comment: @GabrielHeng I've updated the solution based on your feedback.